# How do I get URL parameters on AngularJS SPA when using stateProvider for routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For example, on the last state on the below code I want to get the value of "category" URL parameter so that I can use it to  retrieve some from the database

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",["ui.router"]);
        app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
            $stateProvider
                .state("main", {
                    url: "/",
                    views: {
                        "slider": {
                            templateUrl: "slider.html"
                        },
                        "departments": {
                            templateUrl: "departments.html"
                        },
                        "brands": {
                            templateUrl: "brands.html"
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("cart", {
                    url: "/cart",
                    views: {
                        "cart": {
                            templateUrl: "../account/cart.php"
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("department", {
                    url: "/department/:category",
                    views: {
                        "department": {
                            templateUrl: "department.php"
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller, pass stateParams and instantiate the controller within the views of the last state

```
               .state("department", {
                    url: "/department/:category",
                    views: {
                        "department": {
                            templateUrl: "department.php",
                            controller: "myController"
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
        app.controller('myController', function($stateParams) {
            var param = $stateParams.category;
            document.getElementById("category").value = param;
        });
```